# How to introduce more extensions to UseStaticFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.2, and I always use the following code as cache control for static files:

```
var cachePeriod = env.IsDevelopment() ? "600" : "2592000";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cachePeriod}");
    }
});
```

However this time I'm also using **.webp** images, and I notice that caching is not working for this extension. How can I add extensions to be used by `UseStaticFiles()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cache-Control header controls caching at the request level. So any file served as a response to a request from `UseStaticFiles` will get cached.

The problem here is, `UseStaticFiles` doesn't recognize the mime-type of webp as one handled by the StaticFileHandler, you can fix this by either using `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` and giving it a mime-type IIS understands as a StaticFile and passing that provider into the `StaticFileOptions` or by allowing IIS to serve unknown file types (less secure, but easier/faster):

```
var cachePeriod = env.IsDevelopment() ? "600" : "2592000";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cachePeriod}");
    },
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
```

);

See [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider) for more information on adding the mime type using `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`. Also reference [Adding Static Content MIME Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) for an example of how to modify your web.config to map `.webp` file extensions to the staticContent (Static File Handler) file handler.

Comment: although this seems to be the solution, but I don't get why it's not working for me.

Comment: Did you add the mime type mapping for webp?

Comment: yes, I did, `var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings[".webp"] = "image/webp";
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
              FileProvider =  new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")),
                ContentTypeProvider = provider,
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cachePeriod}");
                }
            });`